# problema con el getSelectedItem() de JComboBox de java

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente problema. tengo una lista de Carreras universitarias, donde cada carrera tiene una lista de Materias. tengo dos `JComboBox` dentro de un panel. en uno cargo las carreras y en el otro, las Materias de la carrera que seleccione en el combo. Ahora bien cuado quiero obtener el OBJETO Carrera, no tengo problemas, pero cuando quiere obtener el OBJETO Materia, no me toma el `getSelectedItem` del combo de materia. les dejo el codigo

CARGO EL COMBO DE CARRERAS

```
public static void actualizarComboCarreras(JComboBox<Carrera> jcCarreras) {
          
        jcCarreras.removeAllItems();

        for(Carrera ca : Facultad.carrerasFacultad) {
            jcCarreras.addItem(ca);
        }
}
```

CARGO EL COMBO DE MATERIAS

```
public static void actualizarComboMaterias(JComboBox<Materia> jcListaMaterias, Carrera c) {
            
        ArrayList<Materia> mate = c.getMaterias(); //lista de materias
    
        jcListaMaterias.removeAllItems();

        for(int i=0; i< mate.size(); i++){
            if(mate.get(i).getNombreCarrera() == nombre){
                jcListaMaterias.addItem(mate.get(i));  //cargo el combo de materias
            }
        }
      }
```

OBTENCION DE OBJETOS DEL COMBO CARRERA

```
Carrera carrerita = (Carrera) PanelInscripcionMateria.jcCarreras.getSelectedItem();
```

OBETENCION DEL OBJETO MATERIA (ESTE NO FUNCIONA)

```
Materia asignatura = (Materia) PanelInscripcionMateria.jcListaMaterias.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Intenta con: `if( nombre.equals( mate.get(i).getNombreCarrera() ) ){`.

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste de que tu ComboBox de materias se llena correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es que estás intentando obtener el elemento seleccionado en el JComboBox de materias utilizando una variable que no se encuentra en el contexto actual. La variable PanelInscripcionMateria.jcListaMaterias se encuentra en una clase diferente a la que estás utilizando para obtener el elemento seleccionado.

Para resolver este problema, debes obtener el JComboBox de materias de la misma clase en la que estás tratando de obtener el elemento seleccionado. Por ejemplo, si estás intentando obtener el elemento seleccionado en un método llamado miMetodo, debes asegurarte de que el JComboBox de materias se encuentre en el contexto de ese método. Una forma de hacerlo es pasando el JComboBox como argumento al método:

```
public void miMetodo(JComboBox<Materia> jcListaMaterias) {
  // Obtén el elemento seleccionado en el JComboBox de materias
  Materia asignatura = (Materia) jcListaMaterias.getSelectedItem();
  // Realiza alguna acción con la materia seleccionada
}
```

Si deseas utilizar el JComboBox de materias en varios métodos diferentes, puedes declararlo como una variable de instancia de la clase en la que se encuentran los métodos:

```
public class MiClase {
  // Declara el JComboBox como una variable de instancia
  private JComboBox<Materia> jcListaMaterias;

  // Constructor que inicializa el JComboBox
  public MiClase() {
    jcListaMaterias = new JComboBox<>();
  }

  public void miMetodo1() {
    // Obtén el elemento seleccionado en el JComboBox de materias
    Materia asignatura = (Materia) jcListaMaterias.getSelectedItem();
    // Realiza alguna acción con la materia seleccionada
  }

  public void miMetodo2() {
    // Obtén el elemento seleccionado en el JComboBox de materias
    Materia asignatura = (Materia) jcListaMaterias.getSelectedItem();
    // Realiza alguna acción con la materia seleccionada
  }
}
```